# Backend return html but frontend does not redirect

Tags: java, html, reactjs

I hit an api endpoint and I checked the network call responses with an html response with status code of 302. However, I don't see the redirect happening on the UI. The redirect is to another application (a different url)

```
export function callThis(payload) {
  const url = "some-path";
  const headers = getHeaders();
  return fetch(url, { method: 'POST', headers: headers, body: 
      JSON.stringify(payload) })
  .then((response) => response.json());
}
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: How are you redirecting? Are you using react router?

Comment: No, I am new to react. I thought it would just redirect after getting the html from the backend. @SakoBu

Answer (score 0):

try to help but with this snippet, you didn't show your "redirect part" if you are using reactjs you should have a look at DOM Router and using Redirect or push history.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `redirect: 'follow'` in the request options.

```
export function callThis(payload) {
  const url = "some-path";
  const headers = getHeaders();
  return fetch(url, { method: 'POST', redirect: 'follow', headers: headers, body: 
      JSON.stringify(payload) })
}
```

If you want to know the redirect url and do manual operation, you have to use `redirect: 'manual'`.

```
export function callThis(payload) {
  const url = "some-path";
  const headers = getHeaders();
  return fetch(url, { method: 'POST', redirect: 'manual', headers: headers, body: 
      JSON.stringify(payload) })
  .then((response) => {
     const redirectUrl = response.url // new redirect url
  })

}
```

Hope this helps!